# Access command from the Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

When I use a macro, that opens a new email from a template, I would also like to access one of the commands from the Quick Access Toolbar and make sure a particular option is selected from the drop-down list on this command.

For example, the tab on the toolbar is called 'Add-Ins' and within this tab the area on the toolbar is called 'custom toolbars'. There is a command in this section entitled 'ACT! History', and I would like to automatically chose 'None' from the drop-down list for this command. I do have a screen grab of the toolbar I can send you if this helps.

The current macro is a very simple one as the text below shows.

```
Sub MakeItem()
    Set newItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\jfield\AppData\[file location]\New Placement!.oft")
    newItem.Display
    Set newItem = Nothing
End Sub
```